# The next row meaning in PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I read a lot article on PHP official documentation about fetching data using PDO that often say "the next row". What is the meaning of that word?

[Like this one](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

When I write the code, the result only displays one record from tables, but what is that mean exactly?

Comment: it refers to the rows from the retrieved result set of your query

Comment: @Ghost or I will say next row in result set, which is practically current row in loop.

Comment: so why did it only retrieve only single record when I made a query that was supposed to retrieve multiple records?

Comment: @januaryananda if you're trying to retrieve all rows then you're looking for `->fetchAll` method